# Include third party scripts as type="module"

Tags: angular, angular-config

Im trying to figure out if there is a way to configure angular.json to include scripts as type="module" assuming the following script needs to load as

```
<script src="scripts.js" type="module"></script>
```

When i try this it does not add type="module". Is there a config to make it do that?

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/third-part/script.js"
]
```

I checked around in the docs but did not see it https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config

If not is there a best practice to include it?